# IIF THEN MS ACCESS 2010

Tags: vba, ms-access

This code has always stumped me, I have two training courses I am trying to find records of which employee has taken them, The code is:

```
SELECT O896IA_VEMPPRSA.EMP_NA, O867IA_VTRAING.SYS_EMP_ID_NR, O867IA_VTRAING.REG_NR,     
O867IA_VTRAING.DIS_NR, O867IA_VTRAING.TNG_SYS_NR
FROM O896IA_VEMPPRSA INNER JOIN O867IA_VTRAING ON O896IA_VEMPPRSA.SYS_EMP_ID_NR =     
O867IA_VTRAING.SYS_EMP_ID_NR
WHERE (((O896IA_VEMPPRSA.EMP_EMT_STS_CD)<>"T"))
GROUP BY O896IA_VEMPPRSA.EMP_NA, O867IA_VTRAING.SYS_EMP_ID_NR, O867IA_VTRAING.REG_NR,     
O867IA_VTRAING.DIS_NR, O867IA_VTRAING.TNG_SYS_NR;
```

I need to find the TNG_SYS_NR 1095 or 1743. If they have the record then I need a Y and if not I need it to show N.

I need it to show Name, ID, Reg, Dis, 1095 Y or N, 1743 Y or N. So if they took both courses I need just one row with all their data and Y for 1743 & for 1095. Right now it shows an employee listed twice with Y for 1095 N 1743 and N for 1095 Y 1743 if they took both.

```
+-----------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------+--------+------+------+
|                EMP_NA             |                  SYS_EMP_ID_NR | REG_NR | DIS_NR | 1095 | 1743 |
+-----------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------+--------+------+------+
|     AMOS,  SHARNELE               |                    1531218     |     20 |     10 | N    | Y    |
|     AMOS,  SHARNELE               |                    1531218     |     20 |     10 | Y    | N    |
|     ANDERSON JERNAGIN,  SHERRY    |                    0354362     |     25 |     80 | N    | Y    |
|     ANDERSON JERNAGIN,  SHERRY    |                    0354362     |     25 |     80 | Y    | N    |
|     BAILEY,  EDWARD               |                    0070433     |     20 |     10 | N    | Y    |
|     BAILEY,  EDWARD               |                    0070433     |     20 |     10 | Y    | N    |
+-----------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------+--------+------+------+
```

Comment: I think you're looking for a `LEFT JOIN` and a `CASE WHEN...THEN...END`

Comment: MS Access SQL does not support `CASE WHEN`.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use `IIF()` to get the calculated result:

```
IIF(O867IA_VTRAING.TNG_SYS_NR IN (1095, 1743), 'Y', 'N')
```

So if you add this to your query it would be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT O896IA_VEMPPRSA.EMP_NA, 
    O867IA_VTRAING.SYS_EMP_ID_NR, 
    O867IA_VTRAING.REG_NR,     
    O867IA_VTRAING.DIS_NR, 
    IIF(O867IA_VTRAING.TNG_SYS_NR IN (1095, 1743), 'Y', 'N') 
FROM O896IA_VEMPPRSA 
INNER JOIN O867IA_VTRAING 
    ON O896IA_VEMPPRSA.SYS_EMP_ID_NR = O867IA_VTRAING.SYS_EMP_ID_NR
WHERE (((O896IA_VEMPPRSA.EMP_EMT_STS_CD)<>"T"));
```

Edit, based on your changes you should be able to use an aggregate function around the IIF:

```
SELECT O896IA_VEMPPRSA.EMP_NA, 
  O867IA_VTRAING.REG_NR, 
  O867IA_VTRAING.DIS_NR,
  max(IIF(O867IA_VTRAING.TNG_SYS_NR IN (1095), 'Y', 'N')) as Class1095 ,
  Max(IIF(O867IA_VTRAING.TNG_SYS_NR IN (1743), 'Y', 'N'))  as Class1743
FROM O896IA_VEMPPRSA 
INNER JOIN O867IA_VTRAING 
  ON O896IA_VEMPPRSA.SYS_EMP_ID_NR = O867IA_VTRAING.SYS_EMP_ID_NR
group by O896IA_VEMPPRSA.EMP_NA, O867IA_VTRAING.REG_NR, O867IA_VTRAING.DIS_NR
```

Comment: @user2119980 What do you mean you need a column for each course?  You want a separate column for the `1095` value and for the `1743` value. If that is the case, then you will use only one value in the `IIF` and create two computed columns.

Comment: @user2119980 the query is using `DISTINCT`, if you are getting duplicates then that means that you have distinct values in each column.

Comment: The difference is the Y and N. There is one for for employees with 1095 Y 1743 N and one 1095 N 1743 Y

Comment: @user2119980 Please edit your original post with some sample data and the desired result.